# how to stop ubuntu from accessing internet via proxy?

Tags: proxy

I used to access internet  with my laptop in campus, which require proxy.

My internet at home do not require proxy -or rather I don't know any proxy setting since I always set browser setting to automatic. When I try to access internet at home with ubuntu it always try to access it with my campus proxy. I have no idea with to stop it.

Browsing is no problem. I can change the setting in firefox easily enough. The problem is with installing new software.

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a bash script for it, for me it sounds easier than setting everything up each time, you could use something like [in this site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_settings) (untested):

```bsh
function proxy(){
    echo -n "username:"
    read -e username
    echo -n "password:"
    read -es password
    export http_proxy="http://$username:$password@proxyserver:8080/"
    export https_proxy="http://$username:$password@proxyserver:8080/"
    export ftp_proxy="http://$username:$password@proxyserver:8080/"
    export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
    echo -e "\nProxy environment variable set."
}
function proxyoff(){
    unset HTTP_PROXY
    unset http_proxy
    unset HTTPS_PROXY
    unset https_proxy
    unset FTP_PROXY
    unset ftp_proxy
    echo -e "\nProxy environment variable removed."
}
```